# What is the difference between "tone" and "impression"?

Tags: meaning

Can somebody explain it for me?I do not understand the differences.

Comment: Since *tone* has multiple meanings (well, as does *expression*), can you please provide a clear context for your question? For example, a short paragraph where they're both discussed. Otherwise it may be closed as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Sometimes I see a question that ask about ton or impression in the text,and I do not understand the meaning or the opinion of the writer or reader.Have you ever read this text?"The Quiet Odyssey"

Comment: This is a short comment that doesn't explain the problem. Please supply written context in your question by *editing* it. It will help us to address the actual problem you're experiencing.

Comment: One of the questions of this text is related to "impression".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A story can have a **tone**.  This tone may make an **impression** on you.